# What's an intuitive explanation of Menger's Theorem?

Tags: graph-theory, induction, intuition

I was reading the proof in [Douglas West's Introduction to Graph Theory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0130144002)

The proof is really long and combines induction with a few cases. How else can I internalize Menger's theorem?

Comment: The theorem solves the following problem: You divide a graph into two subgraphs, A and B. How many nodes do you need to remove to separate A from B? To get an answer, you count the maximum number of distict paths from A to B (paths that do not share any common nodes). Intuitively, you need to cut off all those paths. If you don't cut one of them, A and B are still connected by that path. On the other hand, if you cut all those paths, A and B are truly separated. Therefore the minimum number of nodes to remove to seperate A and B is equal to the distinct paths from A to B.

Comment: So it says the only cut vertices are the endpoints of the internally disjoint paths?

Comment: Also, the number of internally disjoint paths is equal to the minimum size vertex cut?

Comment: A lot of the complication in the proof (iirc) comes from special edge cases with the end points of the path. I don't think that understanding every detail is crutial. It's important to get the initial idea imo. To your second question: Yes, that's what the theorem states.

Comment: The above is for the local version btw. For completeness sake, the global version is similar. Pick two nodes, look how many distinct paths connect them. Do this for all pairs of nodes and take the minimum number of distinct paths $k$. This is the connectivity of the graph, as you need to cut exactly those $k$ paths to separate those two nodes (and therefore the graph). The same idea can be applied to edge-connectivity by looking for edge-independant paths rather than for vertex-independant paths.